# Open Set in $\ell_1$ is open in $\ell_2$or not

Tags: functional-analysis

Is the set $P=\{x \in \ell^1:||x||_1<1\}$ an open set in the normed linear space $(\ell^1,||.||_2)$

I am new to functional analysis, so I have trouble working on this problem.
 I tried to find counter-examples to this problems but I couldn't get any. Neither I was able to prove the statement.
I wrote the definition of open set in this case & tried to move ahead but couldn't.
Please help me out.

***Edit 1***

I feel that the statement is incorrect.
If it is true then for any $a=(a_n)\in P$ there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $B_{||.||_2}(a,\epsilon) \subset P$

So for showing that it is not true, I choose $a=(a_n)=(0,0,0,0 \dots)$

for any $\epsilon>0$ we have $n_0 \in N$ such that $\frac{1}{{n_0}^2}+\frac{1}{(n_0+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(n_0+2)^2}+\dots <\epsilon$

Choose $(x_n)=(\frac{1}{n_0},\frac{1}{n_0+1},\frac{1}{n_0+2},\dots \dots) \in B_{||.||_2}(a,\epsilon)$

but  $(\frac{1}{n_0},\frac{1}{n_0+1},\frac{1}{n_0+2},\dots \dots) \notin P $ as  $\frac{1}{{n_0}}+\frac{1}{(n_0+1)}+\frac{1}{(n_0+2)}+\dots$ diverges

Please verify my solution too.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_n=0$ for all $n$ and $y_n=\frac 1 n$ for $N_1 <n<N_2$, $y_n=0$ for all other $n$. Then  $\|x-y\|_2 \to 0$ as $N_1 \to \infty$  but $\|y\|_1 \to \infty$ as $N_2 \to \infty$. Hence no open ball around $x$ in $\ell^{2}$ norm is contained in the open unit ball w.r.t. $\ell^{1}$.

Comment: Sir, I had added my own answer to the post, can you check it

Comment: @SunShine Yes, your argument is correct.

Comment: sir, I think that my solution doesn't work as the sequence $ x_n $ is not in $\ell^1$

Comment: True, you have to work within $\ell${1}$. @SunShine